# TYPO3 StandaloneView not finding Templates

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-11.x

I am using the StandaloneView to output some data.

The problem I encountered is that the given TemplateRootPath is just ignored.
TYPO3 throws an exception saying that it looked for the template in
/typo3/public/typo3conf/ext//Resources/Private/Templates/
but the given TemplateRootPath is one folder further down in /printView/.

Maybe there is something that went over my head but I am looking for a fix for about one and a half hours now.

```
$standaloneView = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView::class);
$standaloneView->setLayoutRootPaths([
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:<my-extension>/Resources/Private/Layouts/printView/'),
]);
$standaloneView->setPartialRootPaths([
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:<my-extension>/Resources/Private/Partials'),
]);
$standaloneView->setTemplateRootPaths([
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('EXT:<my-extension>/Resources/Private/Templates/printView/'),
]);
$standaloneView->setFormat('html');
$standaloneView->setTemplate('printView/printView');
$standaloneView->assignMultiple([
    //variable assignment
]);

echo $standaloneView->render();
```

*<my-extension> is there on purpose*

Comment: Please use correct slashes, no `EXT:\.../Resources/...`.

Comment: my fault. I inserted the backslash (\\) as the original `<my-extension>` was eaten while shown in the browser. with syntax colouring it seams not necessary any more.

Answer (score 0):

`set...RootPaths(...)` expects an array as parameter.

Maybe you need to change the filename of the template to UpperCamelCase.
That might not be needed for the parameter you use for selection, but the generated filename will have it. (`PrintView.html` instead of `printView.html`)

Answer (score 0):

It's little bit late to the party, but as you already has the paths of your private resources declared within the TypoScript of your ext, you can just read them instead of rewriting (DRY!).

with imports

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface;
```

Just declare a method somewhere in your controller (to retrieve its context):

```php
private function initializeStandAloneView(): StandaloneView
{
    /** @var StandaloneView $view */
    $view = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);

    // As you already has the paths of your private resources declared within the TypoScript, you can just read them instead of rewriting (DRY!)
    $cfg = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);

    $view->setControllerContext($this->controllerContext); // important part
    $view->setLayoutRootPaths($cfg['view']['templateRootPaths']);
    $view->setTemplateRootPaths($cfg['view']['templateRootPaths']);
    $view->setPartialRootPaths($cfg['view']['partialRootPaths']);
    return $view;
}
```

So finally you can use it in action(s) of sample `My` controller to render many different standalone views easily like:

```php
/**
 * Some action in MyController.php
 */
public function jumperAction()
{
    $view = $this->initializeStandAloneView();
    if (1 == 1){
        $view->assign('foo', 'bar');
        return $view->render('Jumper/EverythingOk');
    }
    return $view->render('Jumper/NotFound');
}
```

finally you can create these views in files:
`typo3conf/ext/yourext/Resources/Private/Templates/My/Jumper/EverythingOk.html`
`typo3conf/ext/yourext/Resources/Private/Templates/My/Jumper/NotFound.html`

and really finally, don't forget to clear the cache :D